# PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes returns none in WinRT Bluetooth app?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to establish a connection between my Windows Store App to my Windows Phone over Bluetooth.  I am working with one of the MSDN Bluetooth samples.

However, when I run the app, I get an error message saying "Browsing for peers is not supported".  So I can't even execute a scan for paired Bluetooth devices it seems.  I looked in the code and found this:

```
    public PeerFinderScenario()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        _socketHelper.RaiseSocketErrorEvent += SocketErrorHandler;
        _socketHelper.RaiseMessageEvent += MessageHandler;

        // Scenario 1 init
        _triggeredConnectSupported = (PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes & PeerDiscoveryTypes.Triggered) ==
                                     PeerDiscoveryTypes.Triggered;

        _browseConnectSupported = (PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes & PeerDiscoveryTypes.Browse) ==
                                  PeerDiscoveryTypes.Browse;

        Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
    }
```

At run-time when this initialization call is made, **_browseConnectSupported** is being set to FALSE due to what's coming back from the PeerFinder object.  To be specific **PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes** is equal to "None".  Why is this happening and what do I need to do to get the right value into SupportedDiscoveryTypes?  Is it a manifest declaration issue?  A PC wide Bluetooth settings issue?

I do have a properly functioning Bluetooth dongle.  I know this because I am able to pair with my Windows Phone properly.  Also, in my manifest capabilities section I have requested "InternetClientServer" and "proximity" capabilities, and added a declaration for a Bluetooth serial port:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
  <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
  <!-- Added Bluetooth serial port capability manually -->
  <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
    <m2:Device Id="any">
      <m2:Function Type="name:serialPort" />
    </m2:Device>
  </m2:DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky when using WinRt (Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1) and Bluetooth because you need to manually add the capability. Add this to your 8.1 app's AppManifest:

```
<Capabilities>  <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm"> 
<m2:Device Id="any"> 
  <m2:Function Type="name:serialPort" /> 
</m2:Device>
```

On the Phone, if you're using 8.0, you only need to check off "Proximity and Networking".

Additionally, note that it is required that the two BT devices have been previously paired or they wont be discoverable.

Comment: Thanks.  I added that to the manifest and made sure I had "proximity" and "internetClientServer" in the manifest too.  Still no good.  PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes still comes back as "None".